# mySQL - одна гигантская таблица или сотни маленких?

Tags: mysql, выборка, таблицы

**Дано:**

1. Сайт по изучению иностранных языков.
2. Тысячи пользователей и растёт
3. 7 поддерживаемых языков и они добавляются
4. Для каждого языка есть словарь на сотни тысяч слов. Слова лежат в таблицах dictionary_en (последние две буквы префикс языка), где две колонки `id` и `word` (собственно само слово)

**Требуется:**
Организовать хранение личных словарей для пользователей (переводов слов).

**Вопрос:**
Мне нужно организовать хранение личных словарей для каждого пользователя. При этом любой пользователь может разговаривать на любом языке и изучать любой. Мне нужно хранить данные о том какое слово из какого словаря пользователь перевёл на какой язык.

Если я все переводы всех пользователей буду хранить в одной таблице, то боюсь, что она будет просто огромных размеров и выборка из неё будет отжирать кучу времени.

Если я под каждую пару языков буду создавать таблицу, то утону в их количестве. К примеру для перевода с английского на русский таблица vocabulary_en-ru, на француззский vocabulary_en-fr, и так по 7 таблиц на каждый из 7 языков. В итоге количество таблиц будет увеличиваться геометрически...

Подскажите пожалуйста какой вариант выбрать? Или может я в упор не вижу более элегантной реализации без ударений в обе крайности? Буду благодарен за любые мысли по этому поводу.

Comment: Одна таблица. А правильно построенные индексы позволят читать из нее быстро. В случае InnoDB особое внимание обратите на первичный ключ, так как все табилицы этого формата класторизованы по первичному ключу, т.е. фактически хранят радом близкие значения ключей. По этой причине поиск по первичному ключу всегда быстрее, чем по вторичным.

Comment: А как мне поставить внешние ключи на слова которые лежат в разных таблицах, в зависимости от языка? Нужно или делать столбец с префиксом языка и получить кучу дублей инфы или делать по одному столбцу на язык и получить кучу пустых ячеек?

Comment: Почитайте теорию (ключевая фраза -- *нормальные формы*)

Comment: Всё зависит от того, как вы собираетесь использовать эти данные. Пользователь может переводить только слова из словаря? Переводы тоже из словаря? Пользователи могут добавлять слова в словари? А потом эти слова могут быть удалены редактором? А какие выборки будете строить? В некоторых случаях можно денормализовать данные и существенно ускорить запросы.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаевичОлейник У вас изначально не должно было быть отдельных таблиц для языков. А сейчас уже нормально сделать нельзя, только префикс языка, указывающий на таблицу и id слова, с контролем целостности только на уровне приложения

Comment: @Mike, я базы слов находил в разном формате и так их и сохранял, Поэтому и много таблиц. Но проблем нет соединить всё это в одну, достав только нужную инфу. Но опять же, будет куча слов повторений, когда слово пишется одинаково в разных языках. И размер таблицы... Вот у меня 300к только английских слов... Или я зря беспокоюсь по поводу таблиц с миллионами записей?

Comment: Думаю повторения неизбежны. Можно было бы конечно позволить одному слову лежать в одном экземпляре, а языки в которых оно есть, отражать набором бит в одном поле. Но тут явно возникает проблема что слово имеющее одинаковое начертание в разных языках может по разному переводиться, т.е. по сути это разные слова. А размер таблицы не важен. Ни один запрос не должен работать перебором всей таблицы. Мне больше интересно как сами переводы хранятся, я это сейчас вижу как отдельную таблицу буквально с id слова в одном языке и id в другом и возможно еще какие то атрибуты "предпочитаемости"

Answer (score 0):

Одна таблица выглядит более привлекательным решением, а если будет большая то поделите на [партиции](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html). Это почти то же самое, что вы хотите сделать, только автоматически. У вас будто одна таблица, а на самом деле несколько (грубо говоря).